# how to draw a circle on touch in cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, geometry

I want to create a circle on touch. The following code is creating its by default. I am calling the function in touchbegan.

```
void PlayScene::draw()
{
glLineWidth(5);
cocos2d::ccDrawColor4B(0, 255, 255, 255);
cocos2d::ccDrawCircle( ccp(200/2, 500/2), 50, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 50, true);
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Note that you can't call draw, you have to wait for cocos2d to call the draw method. Playscene needs to have been added as child.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake, you overrided `draw` method so that the `draw` from `Scene` is not called. You should add `Scene::draw()` in your draw implementation.

Yet @LearnCocos2d is right, you should not call `draw()` by yourself. Place this code in some method that will be called on touch.